# Excel / VBA /Formula Re-sorting a number series

Tags: excel, vba, algorithm, sorting, series

I have a data series with always four-digit numbers that are unique (not multiple) in one column (column M). The digits in the numbers all go from 1 to n (in this case up to 7) and represent all possible combinations.

1234 (1)
1345 (2)
1456 (3)
1671 (4)
...
2345 (1)
1712
1713
2456 (2)
...
3456 (1)
2671 (3)
1714
3567 (2)
...
7123 (1)
7234 (2) etc.

I now need a VBA code or a formula that sorts the numbers according to the following scheme:
sort so that the numbers always start with the initial digits 1,2,3,4,5,6 to n (in this case 7), always repeating cyclically.
Always select the first number from the existing data series (column I) (regardless of the size of the number) to which criterion 1 applies and once this number is listed in the new column, do not use it again in the next search so that all numbers are still listed exactly once in the new column.
In the example above, first the (1) numbers, then the (2) numbers and so on.

I tried the following Code:

```vb
Sub SortiereUndFilter()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Uebersicht") 
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim uniqueNumbers() As String
    ReDim uniqueNumbers(1 To lastRow - 2)
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim currentNumber As String
    Dim n As Long
    n = 7 ' 7 = die Anzahl der verschiedenen Anfangsziffern in den Zahlen
    
    ' Durchlaufe die Daten in Spalte I und fülle das Array uniqueNumbers
    For i = 3 To lastRow
        currentNumber = ws.Cells(i, "I").Value
        If InStr(Join(uniqueNumbers, ","), currentNumber) = 0 Then
            uniqueNumbers(i - 2) = currentNumber
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Sortiere uniqueNumbers nach der Anfangsziffer
    Dim sortedNumbers() As String
    ReDim sortedNumbers(1 To UBound(uniqueNumbers))
    j = 1
    For i = 1 To n
        For k = 1 To UBound(uniqueNumbers)
            If Left(uniqueNumbers(k), 1) = CStr(i) Then
                sortedNumbers(j) = uniqueNumbers(k)
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next k
    Next i
    
    ' Schreibe die sortierten Zahlen in Spalte K
    For i = 1 To UBound(sortedNumbers)
        ws.Cells(i + 2, "K").Value = sortedNumbers(i)
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Excel is sorting like 1234,1345,1456,1567,1235,1346 and so on...

Comment: I don't understand the sorting. What does "always repeating cyclically" mean? "Always select the first number from the existing data series (column I)" What is column I? " to which criterion 1 applies " what is criterion 1? Maybe some sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: What's the content in the column I?

Comment: When looking for a number beginning with digit `x`, should it always start at the top of the column?  Or continue after the position of the last number found?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out maybe:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim data, out, ws As Worksheet, i As Long, digit As Long, rwOut As Long, ub As Long
    Dim found As Boolean, t
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    t = Timer
    'picking up two columns so we can use the second column to cache the first digit
    data = ws.Range("I2:K" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    ub = UBound(data, 1)
    ReDim out(1 To ub, 1 To 1) 'array for sorted output
    
    For i = 1 To ub
        'populate second column with first digit (for faster comparisons)
        data(i, 2) = CLng(Left(data(i, 1), 1)) 
    Next i
    
    rwOut = 0
    Do
        found = False
        For digit = 1 To 7
            For i = 1 To ub
                If data(i, 2) = digit Then 'checking second column to avoid conversions
                    rwOut = rwOut + 1
                    out(rwOut, 1) = data(i, 1)  'take value from col 1
                    If rwOut = ub Then Exit Do  'no more values to find
                    data(i, 2) = 0              'clear this entry
                    found = True
                    Exit For 'found one!
                End If
            Next i
        Next digit
        If Not found Then Exit Do 'exit when no values were found
    Loop
    
    ws.Range("K2").Resize(ub).Value = out
    Debug.Print Timer - t
    
End Sub
```

**EDIT**: I like this one better

```vb
Sub Tester2()
    Const MAX_DIGIT As Long = 7
    Dim data, out, ws As Worksheet, i As Long, digit As Long, rwOut As Long, ub As Long
    Dim found As Boolean, t, digits() As Collection, d As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    t = Timer
    
    data = ws.Range("I2:I" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    ub = UBound(data, 1)
    ReDim out(1 To ub, 1 To 1) 'array for sorted output
    
    ReDim digits(1 To MAX_DIGIT)
    For digit = 1 To MAX_DIGIT
        Set digits(digit) = New Collection 'initialize collections
    Next digit
    
    For i = 1 To ub 'loop over all the source data
        d = CLng(Left(data(i, 1), 1))
        'add the number in the appropriate collection
        If d > 0 And d <= MAX_DIGIT Then digits(d).Add data(i, 1)
    Next i
    
    rwOut = 0
    Do
        found = False
        For digit = 1 To 7
            With digits(digit)
                If .Count > 0 Then
                    rwOut = rwOut + 1
                    out(rwOut, 1) = .Item(1) 'get the next value
                    .Remove 1                '...and remove from collection
                    found = True             'something was found
                End If
            End With
        Next digit
        If Not found Then Exit Do 'exit when no values were found
    Loop
    
    ws.Range("K2").Resize(ub).Value = out
    Debug.Print Timer - t
    
End Sub
```